# Условие в регулярном выражении

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть простое регулярное выражение:

```
new RegExp('('+this.name+'=).*(&)', 'g')
```

Нужно проверить -  если строка заканчивается символом: `&` то взять все содержимое между `=` и `&`.

Иначе взять все до конца строки

Возможно ли такое условие?

Comment: `new RegExp(this.name+'=[^&]*', 'g')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
// дана строка
let str = '?year=2001&hall=6&months=7'

function genRE(alias) {
    return new RegExp('(' + alias + '=)[^&]*(&|$)');
}

//заменяем содержимое между = и (& или концом строки)
str = str.replace(genRE('year'), "$12019$2")
          .replace(genRE('months'), "$102$2");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо но мне необходимо получать подстроку в обоих случаях даже если нет амперсанда, то есть мне нужно заменить get параметр который например может стоять в центре строки, я проверил ваш код -  мне кажется это не то что нужно

Comment: @ended обновил.

Comment: @ended и приведите пример строки, чтобы быстрее решить проблему.

Comment: ?year=2001&hall=6&months=7

Comment: @ended ответ обновил, я надеюсь это то, что вы хотели получить.

Comment: Да то что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```js
new RegExp('\\b('+this.name+'=).*?(&|$)', 'g');
```

Но, возможно, вам просто нужно [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)?

Comment: Тоже рабочий вариант, спасибо